# Replacement method in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

What is the custom replacement methods through the Controller as the beforeFilter method is deprecated:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('@GetParameter', ['only' => ['show', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy']]);
}

public function GetParameter(Route $route)
{
    $this->parameters = Parameter::findOrFail($route->getParameter('parameters'));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In regards to replacing filters you would use **middleware** instead.

[Laravel Docs - Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware)

[Laravel Docs - Controller Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#controller-middleware)

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middelware('yourmiddleware', ['only' => ['show', 'edit', ...]]);
}
```

**Update:**

After seeing your code, I do not believe you need filters/middleware at all. It looks like you are recreating the functionality of [Route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding).

Example (using implicit binding):

```
Route::get('user/{user}', 'UserController@show');

// UserController
public function show(User $user)
{
    // $user is a User model that was resolved by its primary key
}
```

Comment: and as I register my middleware? if in this case it is a method personalized in Controller?

Comment: I dont know what you mean by personalized.

Comment: This is my code this filter driver and I have to get the record to modify and delete [Code](http://laravel.io/bin/okm8P)

Comment: Updated with more specific answer based on your code.